# How to draw the elements?

Tags: python, opengl, glfw

I was developing a game using Python, Modern OpenGL and GLFW, yes I know it is more difficult but I like to program even then ok. Until now the game's performance was very good, the FPS was between 90 to 100 frames per second, but at one point in the game I had to draw several different objects in different regions in the game simultaneously, at that moment the FPS dropped to 30 to 40 because of the quantity, nothing too serious, but I still didn’t want this drop to happen so following the tutorial on the site: https://open.gl/drawing I tried using glDrawElements to try to draw everything in one shot, but before to implement this in my game, I decided to test it in a simpler program and it ended up not working, the code runs but nothing appears, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
import glfw, time, ctypes, math, pyrr
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *

glfw.init()

glfw.window_hint(glfw.SAMPLES, 4)

w = glfw.create_window(640, 480, "Galeria das Sombras", None, None)

glfw.make_context_current(w)

v = """
#version 330
in layout(location=0) vec3 posicao;
in layout(location=1) vec2 textura;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform vec3 def;
uniform vec3 pos;
uniform vec3 scale;
uniform float giro;
uniform float giro2;
out vec2 texcords;
void main(){
    texcords = textura;
    vec3 p = vec3(posicao.x*scale.x,posicao.y*scale.y,posicao.z*scale.z);
    p = p+def;
    p = vec3(-sin(giro)*p.z+cos(giro)*p.x,p.y,sin(giro)*p.x+cos(giro)*p.z);
    p = vec3(p.x,-sin(giro2)*p.z+cos(giro2)*p.y,sin(giro2)*p.y+cos(giro2)*p.z);
    p = p+pos;
    gl_Position = view*vec4(p,1);
}
"""

f = """
#version 330
in vec2 texcords;
uniform vec3 cor;
uniform sampler2D texinfo;
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(cor,1)*texture(texinfo,texcords);
}
"""

shader = compileProgram(compileShader(v,GL_VERTEX_SHADER),compileShader(f,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

tudo = [-1,-1,0,0,1,
        1,-1,0,1,1,
        1,1,0,1,0,
        -1,1,0,0,0]

tudo = np.array(tudo, np.float32)

VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(tudo)*4, tudo, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 20, ctypes.c_void_p(12))
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

tudo = [0,1,2,
        1,2,3]

tudo = np.array(tudo, np.float32)

VBE = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBE)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(tudo)*4, tudo, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glUseProgram(shader)

view = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, 640/480, .1, 1000)
p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
glUniformMatrix4fv(p, 1, GL_FALSE, view)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)

from PIL import Image

t = glGenTextures(1)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, t)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
buffer = Image.open("p.jpg")
data = buffer.tobytes()
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, buffer.size[0], buffer.size[1], 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data)

girar = 0
tempo = glfw.get_time()
tfps = glfw.get_time()
fps = 0
action = 0

while not glfw.window_should_close(w):
    glfw.swap_buffers(w)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    view = pyrr.matrix44.create_perspective_projection_matrix(60, glfw.get_window_size(w)[0]/glfw.get_window_size(w)[1], .1, 1000)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "view")
    glUniformMatrix4fv(p, 1, GL_FALSE, view)
    glViewport(0,0,glfw.get_window_size(w)[0],glfw.get_window_size(w)[1])
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "cor")
    glUniform3f(p, 1, 0, 0)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "def")
    glUniform3f(p, 0, 0, 0)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "scale")
    glUniform3f(p, 1, 1, 1)
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "giro")
    glUniform1f(p, girar*math.pi/180)
    if glfw.get_time() - tempo > 1/60:
        girar+=1
        tempo = glfw.get_time()
        if action > 0:
            action-=.05
        if action < 0:
            action = 0
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "giro2")
    if glfw.get_key(w, glfw.KEY_W) and action == 0:
        action = 2
    if action > 1:
        glUniform1f(p, (1-(action-1))*-90*(math.pi/180))
    else:
        glUniform1f(p, action*-90*(math.pi/180))
    p = glGetUniformLocation(shader, "pos")
    glUniform3f(p, 0, 0, -10)
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
    # glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4)
    fps+=1
    if glfw.get_time() - tfps > 1:
        print("FPS:",fps)
        fps = 0
        tfps = glfw.get_time()
    glfw.poll_events()
    time.sleep(1/240)

glfw.destroy_window(w)
glfw.terminate()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data type of the array of indices has to be integral. The type has to correspond to the type specification in the draw call

> ```py
> glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)
> ```

Use `np.uint32` rather than `np.float32` for the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`:

<s>`tudo = np.array(tudo, np.float32)`</s>

```py
tudo = np.array(tudo, np.uint32)
```

---

The type of the last argument of `glDrawElements` is a pointer (`c_void_p`):

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0)`</s>

Either

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

or

```py
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

---

Furthermore, your indices are wrong:

<s>`tudo = [0,1,2, 1,2,3]`</s>

```py
tudo = [0,1,2, 0,2,3]
```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but on my computer it made no difference, it keeps running but nothing appears.

Comment: @ArthurSally I've extended the answer.